# Is it possible have the PDF bookmark level go deeper than the table of contents depth?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

Is it possible to make the bookmarks in the PDF go a level deeper than the table of contents goes? I'm using KOMA-script, `scrreprt` if that matters.

If the table of contents displays two levels:

```
1. Level 1
    1.1. Level 2
2. Level 1
    2.1. Level 2
```

Is it then possible to make the PDF bookmarks to display:

```
1. Level 1
    1.1. Level 2
        1.1.1 Level 3
2. Level 1
```

The bottom line is that I want them to have independent level depths, if that's possible.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The package [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) allows settings like this. The author is Heiko Oberdiek.

The package has the option `bookmarksdepth`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{foo bar}
\subsection{foo bar foo}

\chapter{bar}
\section{bar foo}
\subsection{bar foo bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Macro: I wonder what is `screeprt`? I tried to change it to `article` but somehow it gave me errors says, `Something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item`, any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chan: Dou you mean `scrreprt`? This is one of the documentclasses provided by KOMA. It is the equivalent to `report`. By changing the documentclass to `article` you have to compile more than once. An other important fact `article` doesn't define the element `chapter`. The highest level ist `section` (and part ;-) ).