# Displayed and PDF table of contents with different depths

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am writing a document with several sections and subsections, using the [amsart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) template. I would like the following:

- A short table of contents at the start of the document, which only includes the sections.
- Bookmarks on the generated PDF which includes sections and subsections, as is typically done automatically via the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package.

The command `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` modifies both, and there doesn't seem to be a easy way to set them separately. Using the [shorttoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc) package I had a hack solution (involving generating a `.toc` file first), but it also replaced all of my headers to just display "Contents."

Below is a MWE with the above in mind. I've added a lot of sections and text to ensure the headers are correct (author on even pages, title on odd pages which is the default amsart style).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Testing}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[2-5]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[6-9]
\section{Second subsection}
\lipsum[10]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[11-13]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[14-16]

\end{document}
```

This generates the correct bookmarks/links in the generated PDF (using Zathura for instance), but I would only like it to display "First Section" and "Second Section" in the contents. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is it possible have the PDF bookmark level go deeper than the table of contents depth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18743)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the bookmark depth independantly from tocdepth with the `bookmarksdepth` key:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}

\title{Testing}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[2-5]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[6-9]
\section{Second subsection}
\lipsum[10]
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[11-13]
\subsection{Second subsection}
\lipsum[14-16]

\end{document}
```

[image]